# RHEL 5 Mounting RAW devices

Tags: rhel5, hard-drive

I Hope this is a simple question.

What is the best practice to mount RAW drives on RHEL 5. I have found a couple of approaches but i'm not sure what the correct one is as i have found references to some being depreciated.

As an aside, i would also need to know how to assign ownership rights as they shouldn't be owned by root if its included in the mounting process.

Comment: Which approaches have you found?

Comment: The two that i did find were

1. rawdevice service (etc/sysconfig/rawdevices) 
2. Adding rules and access rights to etc/udev/rules.d/60-raw.rules.

BTW. My current setup is using the 2nd option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sysconfig/rawdevices is considered deprecated in RHEL5, use the udev method.
As for ownership, use the following in /etc/udev/rules.d/60-raw.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="raw*", OWNER=="root", GROUP=="disk", MODE=="0660"
```

Also, try checking out the [following article](http://magazine.redhat.com/2008/09/17/tips-and-tricks-how-do-i-add-raw-device-mapping-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-5/)

Answer (score 0):

The raw device mapping is sloppy because applications have been encouraged to open with O_DIRECT for so long. Unfortunately vendors have been slow to react, and people have been left suffering with dangerously confusing raw device configuration.

Always ask the vendor when they expect to support O_DIRECT, if you're forced to use the /dev/raw stuff.